# Excel formula: column matching for a Y/N

Tags: excel

I have a master list of grant names (A column) and separate tab for a smaller number of grants that fit into a given category. In the B-E column of the master list, I want an equation that would search for the grant name (A1) in the list of grants listed in the other tab (A1:A15). If A1 matches one of the grants in Tab 2 A1:A15, i want the equation to say "yes" and if not, to say nothing. I know how to check for matching content between two cells, but not a number of cells like in this project

Thanks in advance!
Elise

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, unfortunately this is not a code writing service. Please provide an example, and what you've attempted. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS('Tab2'!:A:A,A1),"Yes","")
```

Or:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,'Tab2'!A:A,0)),"Yes","")
```

Comment: I would put `Tab2` in single quotes just incase the tab name contains a space (e.g. `'Tab 2'`) but otherwise agree. +1

Comment: They both work! Thank you! Now, when copying down to the other rows, the equation adjusts all values.  =IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,'Tab2'!A1:5A,0)),"Yes","") turns to =IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,'Tab2'!A2:A6,0)),"Yes","") instead of =IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,'Tab2'!A1:A5,0)),"Yes",""). How do I lock part of the equation?

Comment: @EliseHoover that is why I used `A:A` but to lock it you would `A$1:A$5`

Comment: @EliseHoover if this answered your question, please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.